# Correct name for String manipulation in Java

Tags: java

Could you please clarify - which word should be used to describe this process of creating String object from literal:

String obj = "value";

As I understand it isn't correct to say that here we have autoboxing since it is actual only for primitive types, but is there any other special key word for this process?

Comment: Initialization?

Comment: Setting. "I'm setting obj to the string literal 'value'". I like the suggestion "initialization."

Comment: Yes, it seems initialization fits, but I thought there is special word for String case..like for primitive..Anyway thanks.

Comment: But is there any description for process when we have "new String("value") in runtime instead of = "value" in the original code?

Comment: @XZen There's no name for doing that (`new String("value")`) except to call it unnecessary and stupid.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you are looking for is **INITIALIZATION**

And as an extra of this I would try to explain the difference of the two initialization a String class can have.

for String there is a difference between `String obj = "value";` and `String obj = new String("value");`

```
String obj = "value";
```

> When we create a String using double quotes, JVM looks in the String
>   pool to find if any other String is stored with same value. If found,
>   it just returns the reference to that String object else it creates a
>   new String object with given value and stores it in the String pool.

`String obj = new String("value");`

> When we use new operator, JVM creates the String object but don’t
>   store it into the String Pool. We can use intern() method to store the
>   String object into String pool or return the reference if there is
>   already a String with equal value present in the pool.

reference: http://www.journaldev.com/1321/java-string-interview-questions-and-answers

Comment: While this is interesting, I don't think it's relevant to the question. edit: Boann, I agree with you

Comment: Changed the reply in order to be accurated and at the same time, as interesting as before

Comment: Thanks, @RamonBoza, it's what I'm talking about, so when we use String obj = "value";  - JVM behave like when we initialize primitive types - it uses some "cache", but for primitive types we have special word - autoboxing. Here we have similar logic, but haven't special word. This is what confused me. Please correct me if  I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It is called **Definition**.
You are 'Declaring' a String variable, and 'Initializing' it to a particular value.

Check out the below link for a better clarification:
http://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap14/subsection2.1.1.4.html

and to quote a part of it:
``` So far when we have ``declared'' a variable, we have meant that we have told the compiler about the variable; i.e. its type and its name, as well as allocated a memory cell for the variable (either locally or globally). This latter action of the compiler, allocation of storage, is more properly called the definition of the variable. The stricter definition of declaration is simply to describe information ``about'' the variable. ```

Comment: Nope... I just realised that when you Declare and Initialize in one line, it is commonly called Definition.

Comment: Thanks for that, @Pankaj, I know that it is definition, but I was confused by another fact. It's that String is special case, when we use literal like: String obj = "value" JVM behave like with primitive types, so I expected that for this case (String obj = "xxx") there are some special description or key word like for autoboxing of primitive types

Comment: Hmmm... @XZen, i don't think there is a special term just for this case. If there is, i am unaware of it...

Answer (score 1):

You are actually doing two things in that statement. You are *declaring* the variable `obj` of type `String`, and you are *initializing* it to "value."

Another term for the latter is *assignment*. Initialization is a specific form of assignment where you're doing it for the first time.